# How to remove arrays inside array if a condition is met

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an object schema that looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":"ObjectId(""30t00594537da2r7awe083va"")",
   "balances":{
      "intraday":[
         [
            1630939075734,
            1899.09
         ],
         [
            1630939435939,
            1899.32
         ],
         [
            1632306730756,
            0
         ],
         [
            1632306759376,
            0
         ],
         [
            1632272012916,
            1372.22
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to remove all arrays within "balances.intraday" array whose the second element is equal to 0.

so my desired array will looks like this:

```
  {
   "_id":"ObjectId(""30t00594537da2r7awe083va"")",
   "balances":{
      "intraday":[
         [
            1630939075734,
            1899.09
         ],
         [
            1630939435939,
            1899.32
         ],
         [
            1632272012916,
            1372.22
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried to use the $pull command but it only removes the index and not the whole array.

**======================= Edit =======================**

Thanks to **Tom Slabbaert** the solution is as follows :

```
db._get_collection().update_many(
{},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "balances.intraday": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$balances.intraday",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$this",
                  1
                ]
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) for this, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "balances.intraday": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$balances.intraday",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$$this",
                  1
                ]
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mXd56ANEOY2)

Comment: This solution does not completely delete the array but only the index itself, how do I delete the entire array ?

so instead of getting this :  
        [
          1.632306730756e+12
        ]

I would like to remove the entire array from the intraday array.

Comment: i updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much sir , works like a charm ! 
for those who seek for pymongo solution , its the same as Tom Slabbaert answer only to wrap every command with "" . so it looks like this : 

db._get_collection().update_many({}, [{"$set": {"balances.intraday": {
        "$filter": {"input": "$balances.intraday", "cond": {"$ne": [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$$this", 1]}, 0]}}}}}]). 

Thanks again man !